# Виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

Можно ли создать виртуальное окружение папки на Windows 10 для Python через PowerShell?
На `$ virtualenv venv` ругается.

Comment: Можно конечно, только доллар-то из команды уберите

Comment: Совет на  будущее - если что-то ругается, то ругань надо а) прочитать и постараться понять, скорее всего после этого станет понятно, как решить проблемы; если же осталось непонятно,то б) скопировать и вставить в вопрос.